# Unable to change the font size of poster

Tags: fontsize

```
\documentclass[a0, landscape, 20pt]{sciposter}
```

is my declaration.
I try to change the 20pt to other smaller values, but it does not work. What is the solution to this situation?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sciposter`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sciposter) only provides a limited number of font size options at the document class level: `14pt`, `17pt`, `20pt`, `25pt`, `30pt`, `36pt`. Any font size option other than these will leave you with the following warning in you `.log`:

```
Package poster Warning: Unknown option XXpt on input line XX.
```

If you want something other than the set font sizes, you could consider a different document class. But that really depends on what you're after exactly in terms of the output.

Comment: how do i set font sizes for figures if i use `caption` package? it seems to ignore any of these

Comment: @ivan866: You should ask a new question with a complete minimal example that replicates the issue.